# Boot on USB disk, downgrading Ubuntu

Tags: live-usb, downgrade

I would like to downgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 14.04 since my MacBook is very slow. I have made a bootable USB disk with startup disk creator but when I reboot my computer, it starts 16.04.

How can I boot on this USB disk and downgrade my Ubuntu ?

Thanks

Comment: I believe the only way to downgrade is a total format....

Comment: @eyoung100 ho how do I do that?

Comment: Does your MacBook have OS X installed?

Comment: @eyoung100 no i formatted to Ubuntu only install

Comment: Then Run the 14.04 installer, and when asked to choose the install location, select Entire Disk.  This will format your current 16.04 install including your home directory, ie all data will be lost.